# Symfony2 + Bootstrap multiple choice (MagicSuggest or similar)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-forms

There is an amazing multiple selection combo box for Bootstrap3, the [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/) which is not compatible with Symfony2 due to the way info is passed to the server, as can be read here in [this issue](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/issues/158).

Is there any valid alternative to it, or do you know how I could touch the original code of MagicSuggest to achieve the desired result?

Thank you!

SN

Comment: Look for zenstruck\formbundle. Note that your question is actually off topic here on SO as it asks to recommand for a library.

Comment: Thank you. I knew the recommendation for a vendor was off topic, did not know about a library. My apologies.